# How to configure zip4j to use bouncycastle encryption (fips provider)

Tags: java, bouncycastle, fips, zip4j

I need to create a password protected (encrypted) ZIP in java and I am using zip4j for it. I now need to use a specific cryptographic provider (bouncy castle fips version) with zip4j but I could not figure out how to configure zip4j to use it if at all possible

Any tips/samples would be greatly appreciated

Thank you
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible.

zip4j uses its own AES Implementation, as you can see here: https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j/tree/master/src/main/java/net/lingala/zip4j/crypto

Comment: Thank you @Motscha. Did not occur to me that it might use its own implementation

Comment: No Problem, glad I could help you :)

One Quick Note: Please be so kind and accept my Answer so that user users that might stumble upon this Question can see that this is indeed the answer.

It is a common practice to accept the answer instead of commenting.

These two links will do more explaining then my comment.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers